# Deploying a component developed using angular-starter in to npm

Tags: angular, deployment, npm, webpack

I have developed some angular components using the Angular Starter Kit - angular-starter - https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter

I would like to package them and deploy in NPM so that other projects can use them. However from the documentation , this was not clear

Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In case if any one is interested , after doing the production build using

```
ng build --prod
```

You can use the command

```
npm publish dist
```

to publish to npm. However you will need an npm account and should be logged in to npm using the npm login command to run npm publish dist